# .Net not properly generating code for substitutiongroups and multiple levels of inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, xsd

I have an XML schema with a model with multiple levels of inheritance like so, where A and B are abstract types:

```
+----+     +----+     +---+
| A* |<-+--| B* |<-+--| D |
+----+  |  +----+  |  +---+
        |  +---+   |  +---+
        +--| C |   +--| E |
           +---+      +---+
```

The schema looks like this:

```xml
<element name="Thing">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="app:number"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>

<element name="number" type="app:numberType" abstract="true"/>
<complexType name="numberType" abstract="true"/>

<element name="madeUpNumber" type="app:madeUpNumberType" substitutionGroup="app:number"/>
<complexType name="madeUpNumberType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="app:numberType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="value" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<element name="realNumber" type="app:realNumberType" substitutionGroup="app:number" abstract="true"/>
<complexType name="realNumberType" abstract="true">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="app:numberType"/>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<element name="evenNumber" type="app:evenNumberType" substitutionGroup="app:realNumber"/>
<complexType name="evenNumberType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="app:realNumberType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="value" type="int"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<element name="oddNumber" type="app:oddNumberType" substitutionGroup="app:realNumber"/>
<complexType name="oddNumberType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="app:realNumberType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="value" type="int"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

I tried generating client C# code using Visual Studio Express 2012, but this is what I got:

```cs
public partial class Thing : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private madeUpNumberType itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("madeUpNumber", Order=0)]
    public madeUpNumberType Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }
    ...
```

Since I only get a `madeUpNumberType` in `Thing`, I can recieve this response

```xml
<Thing>
    <madeUpNumber>
        <value>Infinity!</value>
    </madeUpNumber>
</Thing>
```

but not this

```xml
<Thing>
    <evenNumber>
        <value>8</value>
    </evenNumber>
</Thing>
```

Is there anything I can do except manually poking around in the generated Reference.cs?